# libxml linker error

Tags: linux, compiling, linker

I've got an app which won't link, giving error:

```
/usr/lib64/libcroco-0.6.so.3: undefined reference to `xmlGetProp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib64/libcroco-0.6.so.3: undefined reference to `xmlFree@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib64/libcroco-0.6.so.3: undefined reference to `xmlHasProp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
```

I've got libxml installed:

```
libxml++.x86_64                  2.33.2-1.fc15      @koji-override-    0/$releasever
libxml++-devel.x86_64            2.33.2-1.fc15      @fedora                     
libxml2.i686                     2.7.8-6.fc15       @fedora                     
libxml2.x86_64                   2.7.8-6.fc15       @koji-override-0/$releasever
libxml2-devel.x86_64             2.7.8-6.fc15       @fedora                     
libxml2-python.x86_64            2.7.8-6.fc15       @koji-override-0/$releasever
```

Any ideas? Maybe libcroco was compiled with older version and I need older libxml installed?

Comment: Show us the linker command line, and the output of `ldd /usr/lib64/libcroco-0.6.so.3`.

Comment: thanks, libcroco was looking for libxml in a strange place :) works now...

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Which strange place was it? How did you fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that the .so files aren't in a directory the linker looks for libraries in.  Can you find out where the file `libxml2.so` resides, and then put that directory on the link command line  with a `-L` ?

Comment: yeah, for some reason, libcroco was looking for the file in the absolutely wrong place :)

Answer (score 0):

Although is a versioned symbol it still seems to be the current, linkable, version of the symbol in 2.7.8 as far as I can see.

I take it you do have `-lxml2` on your link line? If you're relying on linking to `libcroco` pulling it in then that won't work on recent Fedora releases and you will need to link against it directly.

Comment: yes, i've got -lxml2...